# new kinect-PC tutorial

Tags: kinect

I am trying to build a game for kinect which has been just released on this Feb.
I was trying to find the tutorial for this because I am really new to this platform.
Could anyone please tell me some good tutorials for this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kinect sdk official apps, you have to look for [channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect). There is no a lot tuttorial right now (books..etc) But if you want to look another frameworks like [OpenNi](http://75.98.78.94/default.aspx) (The OpenNI organization is an industry-led, not-for-profit organization formed to certify and promote the compatibility and interoperability of Natural Interaction (NI) devices, applications and middleware.)you can check [kinecthacks](http://kinect.dashhacks.com/) which is non official. 
 There is only one book at the [market](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430238887) right now, named meet the kinect which is not only about kinect sdk but its good for starting, but after 1 month there will be more good books about hacking kinect sdk.